# Batch Transcription and LUIS Integration

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have a requirement to do integration between the batch transcription and LUIS wherein I will pass the transcriptions as such to LUIS and get the intent of the audio.

As far as I know we can pass the data for intent analysis to LUIS as a query which accepts only 500 characters.

So here comes the question is it possible to pass the full transcription from speech to text batch transcription API to LUIS for intent analysis or we have to feed the data in chunks to LUIS ?

If we feed the data in chunks(500 characters) how we will get the overall intent of the audio, since different utterances may lead to different top level intent.

I have done a lot of research on this reading the microsoft documentations , but could not find any answer.

Please suggest on the best possible way to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I don't think we can get the intent of the audio accurately if feed the data in chunks. I think we'd better to limit the length of the character to no more than 500. If it is longer than 500, just return error message(or not allow it longer than 500).

By the way, is it possible to get rid of unimportant words before sending to LUIS ?

Comment: thanks for the reply but in my case, I want to know the intent of the whole conversation , which will be more than 500 characters. You can always implement the logic to get rid of the unnecessary keywords (nothing provided by luis) , but what all you need to get rid of , you need to define that . The list can be long.

Answer (score 0):

Here is LUIS integration with speech service https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/interactive-voice-response-bot#ai-and-nlp-azure-services

We do have a Telephony channel which is currently in private preview, and as such, comes with preview terms (no SLA, etc).
Here are the details about the preview: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-IVR.